# How to fix undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use `null` or omit this value using getStaticprops

Tags: next.js, vercel

i am trying to fetch some data from an api using getStaticProps with next js. It returns the error undefined`cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use`null` or omit this value.

I have amended the code based on the solutions proposed online about the topic but none of them work.

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const propertyForSale = await fetchApi(`${baseUrl}/properties/list?locationExternalIDs=5002&purpose=for-sale&hitsPerPage=6`);
  
  const propertyForRent = await fetchApi(`${baseUrl}/properties/list?locationExternalIDs=5002&purpose=for-rent&hitsPerPage=6`);

  return {
    props: {
      // Initial code
      propertyForSale: propertyForSale?.hits,
      propertyForRent: propertyForRent?.hits,
      
      // the below snippet fixes the issue but return null
      // propertyForSale: propertyForSale?.hits ?? null,
      //propertyForRent: propertyForRent?.hits ?? null,

     //the below snippet fixes the issue but return Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
      // propertyForSale: JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(propertyForSale?.hits))
      //propertyForRent: JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(propertyForRent?.hits)),

    }
  }
}
```

fetchapi.js

```
export const baseUrl = 'https://bayut.p.rapidapi.com'


  
  export const fetchApi = async (url) => {  
      const {result} = await axios.get((url), {
        headers: {
            'x-rapidapi-host': 'bayut.p.rapidapi.com',
            'x-rapidapi-key': process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BAYU_API
          },
      });
      console.log(result);
      return result;
  };
```

Comment: Probably it is because the data you are receiving is not shaped/of type able to be serialized as JSON. What do you get in this console.log?

Comment: Hi @LazarNikolic the console log is not returning anything on the console. i think it is because the error get thrown before the line is processed

Comment: Well, based on what you showed here, console.log should be done before final return from getStaticProps(). If you do this fetch with cURL or Postman, do you get anything?

Comment: @LazarNikolic  get i solved it seems the issue was in my fetch api function. I have to change result to data. Thanks for trying to help... :)

Answer (score 6):

can you try this please?

```
  return {
    props: {
      propertyForSale: propertyForSale?.hits || null,
      propertyForRent: propertyForRent?.hits || null,
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

As [Lazar pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70937425/how-to-fix-undefined-cannot-be-serialized-as-json-please-use-null-or-omit-th#comment125405868_70938345) in his comment, in your question's code snippet, **you're trying to destructure a property that doesn't exist**. And since axios returns an object with the `data` property, you're only left with destructuring the **correct** property:

`const { data } = await axios.get(.....)`

**or**...

```js
const result = await axios.get(.....);

return result.data;
```

if you insist on the `result` thing :D

Answer (score 2):

To fix the error I renamed constant result to data as per below.
I am not sure of what is the reason of this bug, if someone wanna add something to explain the reason why naming the constant data fixed the bug be my guess.

```
export const fetchApi = async (url) => {  
      const {data} = await axios.get((url), {
        headers: {
            'x-rapidapi-host': 'bayut.p.rapidapi.com',
            'x-rapidapi-key': process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BAYU_API
          },
      });
      
      return data;
  };
```

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const propertyForSale = await fetchApi(`${baseUrl}/properties/list?locationExternalIDs=5002&purpose=for-sale&hitsPerPage=6`);
  
  const propertyForRent = await fetchApi(`${baseUrl}/properties/list?locationExternalIDs=5002&purpose=for-rent&hitsPerPage=6`);

  return {
    props: {
      // Initial code
      propertyForSale: propertyForSale?.hits,
      propertyForRent: propertyForRent?.hits,


    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is because axios packs returned data into data variable https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema